# Creating issue in TestLink

Tags: testlink

When i am creating issue in Testlink asking version and not taking any data in version field. Please help me what is version exactly has to be.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABBlv.png)

Answer (score 0):

The **Version** field is empty because you have not specified any versions for your project in JIRA. In my case it was Fix version in JIRA. Currently the rest API is getting an empty list of versions. You can try

> curl -X GET http://xxx.yourjiraserver.com/rest/api/2/project/MX/versions
>   -H 'authorization: Basic usidjdfkbusjiddosksjsjasidDkw'

This will give you an empty list.
Once you set FixVersion for your project in JIRA, this API will return the list of available versions for your project and the Version field will be populated with those versions.

PS: use your own authorization headers. You can use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) for this purpose.